# Question about a closed subspace of a complete space

Tags: real-analysis

Let $J$ be a closed interval. Let $C(J)$ be space of continuous functions on $J$. We know $C(J)$ is a complete metric space with metric $d(x(t),y(t)) = \max_{t \in J} |x - y | $. Consider now

$$ K(J) = \{ x \in C(J) : |x - x_0| \leq \alpha \} $$

where $\alpha, x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. I want to claim that $K(J)$ is closed in $C(J)$.

### My attempt

Take a sequence $(x_n) \subset K(J)$ such that $x_n \to L$. We want to show that $L \in K(J)$. By definition of limit, we can select $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n} $. Then we an find $N$ such that  for all $n > N$, we have

$$ d(x_n,L) = \sup_{t \in J} |x_n(t) - L(t) | < \frac{1}{n}$$

Let $\tau \in J$ such that $| x_n(\tau) - L(\tau)| < \frac{1}{n} $. Then

$$ |L- x_0| \leq |L - x_n| + |x_n - x_0| < \frac{1}{n} + \alpha \to \alpha $$

Hence, $L \in K(J)$. This shows that $K(J)$ is closed.

I would like to hear opinions or feedback on this solution, or maybe a different approach. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a typo in the definition of $K(J)$? With the strict inequality, the set is open, but not closed, for $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: Isn't $K(J)$ just the ball of radius $\alpha$ around the function which is constantly equal to $x_0$? You hardly need to appeal to the definition of $d$. In any metric space it's the case that any closed ball is closed and any open ball is open.

Comment: I agree. But despite the fact that you can do it that way, I would like to ask if my argument makes sense or not. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the introduction of $\tau$. I would leave out that line and go straight to the triangle inequality (but adding in suprema). Otherwise the argument makes sense to me.

Here is a slightly different proof:

If the set $K(J)$ is empty, then $K(J)$ is trivially closed. So assume $K(J)$ is nonempty. Then let ${x_n}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $K(J)$, i.e. $x_n \in C(J)$ such that $d(x_n(t),x_0) \leq \alpha$, for $n=1,2,...$ (note that the $x_n$ are not necessarily unique). The limit of $x_n$, denote it by $x$, lies in $C(J)$ by completeness. By continuity, $d(x_n(t),x_0) \leq \alpha$ implies $d(x(t),x_0) \leq \alpha$ as well, where $x(t)$ is the (uniform) limit of $x_n(t)$. So $x \in K(J)$, and $K(J)$ is closed.